# Show that $\int_{0}^{1}\{P(x)\}^{2}\,dx = (n + 1)^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{1}P(x)\,dx\right)^{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}P(x)\,dx = 0$ for $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$. Show that $$\int_{0}^{1}\{P(x)\}^{2}\,dx = (n + 1)^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{1}P(x)\,dx\right)^{2}$$

If we assume that $P(x) = a_{0}x^{n} + \cdots + a_{n - 1}x + a_{n}$ then we can easily see that $$\int_{0}^{1}\{P(x)\}^{2}\,dx = a_{n}\int_{0}^{1}P(x)\,dx$$ and therefore to solve the given problem we need to show that $$\int_{0}^{1}P(x)\,dx = \frac{a_{n}}{(n + 1)^{2}}$$ Direct integration of the polynomial gives the expression $$\frac{a_{0}}{n + 1} + \frac{a_{1}}{n} + \cdots + \frac{a_{n - 1}}{2} + a_{n}$$ and simplifying this to $a_{n}/(n + 1)^{2}$ does not seem possible. I think there is some nice "integration by parts" trick which will give away the solution, but I am not able to think of it.

Comment: This is problem number $\textbf{1.4.47}$ in the book *Problems in Mathematical Analysis, Vol. III : Integration* by Kaczor Nowak , published by the A.M.S.

Comment: The books comes with solutions, so my comment is also an answer :)

Comment: i dont have this book with me. can you post a hint?

Comment: can you help with how you show that $\int_{0}^{1}\{P(x)\}^{2}\,dx = a_{n}\int_{0}^{1}P(x)\,dx$

Comment: @adam: well $$\int P^2\, dx=\int P(\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n-k}x^{k} )\,dx=a_n\int P\, dx$$ because terms for $k=1,2,\dots,n$ vanish.

Comment: i thought that $\{P(x)\}$ was a fractional part, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^kP(x)\,dx=\frac{a_0}{n+k+1}+\frac{a_1}{n+k}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{k+1}=0$, for each $k=1,2,\ldots,n$

Then $f(x)=\dfrac{a_0}{n+x+1}+\dfrac{a_1}{n+x}+\ldots+\dfrac{a_n}{x+1}=\dfrac{Q(x)}{(n+x+1)\ldots(x+1)}$ (where, Q is a polynomial of degree atmost n), has $n$ zeros $x=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Thus, $Q(x)=c(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-n)$, for some constant $c$.

Also, $(x+1)f(x)=\dfrac{a_0(x+1)}{n+x+1}+\dfrac{a_1(x+1)}{n+x}+\ldots+a_n=\dfrac{Q(x)}{(n+x+1)\ldots(x+2)}$

Setting, $x=-1$ in the above expression $a_n = \dfrac{Q(-1)}{n!}=\dfrac{c(-1)^n(n+1)!}{n!}=c(-1)^n(n+1)$

and, setting $x=0$ we have $\displaystyle \int_0^1 P(x)\,dx = \dfrac{a_0}{n+1}+\ldots+a_n=\dfrac{Q(0)}{(n+1)!}=\dfrac{c(-1)^n}{n+1}$.

Thus $a_n=\displaystyle (n+1)^2\int_0^1 P(x)\,dx$, implying $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\{P(x)\}^{2}\,dx = (n + 1)^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{1}P(x)\,dx\right)^{2}$.

Comment: This is so damn smart!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is yet another solution; it is a little long, but is in fact very simple and non-technical.

**Outline of the proof**

The crucial observation is that the polynomial $Q(x):=((1-x)P(1-x))'$ also has the property in question: integrating by parts, changing the variable, and expanding the binomial, for any $1\le k\le n$ we get
  $$ \int_0^1 x^kQ(x)\,dx = -k\int_0^1 (1-x)P(1-x)x^{k-1}\,dx = -k\int_0^1 P(y) (1-y)^{k-1} y\,dy = 0. $$
We will see that this forces $Q(x)=cP(x)$ with an appropriate coefficient $c$. This is a very strong relation; the result will follow by integrating it against $x^{n+1}$.

**Detailed argument**

With $Q(x)$ defined above, observing that
  $$ \int_0^1 Q(x)\,dx = (1-x)P(1-x)\Big\vert_0^1 = -P(1), $$ 
and letting 
  $$ I:=\int_0^1 P(x)\,dx, $$
we conclude that
  $$ \int_0^1 (IQ(x)+P(1)P(x))x^k\,dx = 0,\qquad 0\le k\le n. $$
As a result, for any polynomial $T$ of degree at most $n$, we have
  $$ \int_0^1 (IQ(x)+P(1)P(x))T(x)\,dx = 0. $$
Applying this with $T(x)=IQ(x)+P(1)P(x)$, we conclude that 
  $$ \int_0^1 (IQ(x)+P(1)P(x))^2\,dx = 0. $$
Therefore, $IQ(x)+P(1)P(x)$ is the zero polynomial:
  $$ IQ(x) = -P(1)P(x). $$
Recalling the definition of $Q(x)$ and switching from $x$ to $1-x$, we get
  $$ I(xP(x))' = P(1)P(1-x). \tag{1} $$
Expanding, $I(xP'(x)+P(x))=P(1)P(1-x)$, and substituting $x=0$ gives
  $$ IP(0)=(P(1))^2. \tag{2} $$
Write 
  $$ J := \int_0^1 x^{n+1} P(x)\, dx. $$
Notice that $J\ne 0$, as otherwise we would have
  $$ \int_0^1 x(P(x))^2\,dx = 0. $$

To complete the proof, we integrate (1) against $x^{n+1}$. In the LHS we get
  $$ I\int_0^1 (xP(x))'x^{n+1}\,dx = I x^{n+2} P(x)\Big\vert_0^1 - (n+1)I \int_0^1 x^{n+1}P(x)\,dx = IP(1)-(n+1)IJ, $$
in the RHS
  $$ P(1) \int_0^1 x^{n+1}P(1-x)\,dx = P(1) \int_0^1 (1-x)^{n+1}P(x)\,dx
      = P(1) (I+(-1)^{n+1}J) $$
(for the last step, we expand the binomial and integrate termwise, observing that all intermediate terms vanish). Hence,
  $$ -(n+1)IJ = (-1)^{n+1} P(1)J; $$
therefore,
  $$ P(1) = (-1)^n(n+1)I. $$
Squaring and using (2),
  $$ IP(0) = (n+1)^2 I^2, $$
and the result follows readily.

Comment: Your solution as well as the one I have accepted are both non-obvious (at least to me). I wonder how you arrived at this. +1

Comment: Considering the linear space of all polynomials of degree at most $n$, the assumption $\int_0^1 P(x)x^kdx=0$ leaves just one degree of freedom, so that every two polynomials satisfying this condition must be proportional. I then used trial and error (and much intuition) to find yet another polynomial satisfying this condition (which is $Q$ in my solution).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $P(x)$ is a linear combination of $1$ and $x, x^2$, $\ldots$, $x^n$ and is perpendicular to the subspace generated by $x, x^2$, $\ldots$, $x^n$. Therefore $P$ gives the direction of the vertical component of $1$.

Now, we must show that
$$\frac{\langle 1, P\rangle ^2 }{\|P\|^2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$
that is, $d(1, \langle x,x^2, \ldots, x^n\rangle)^2=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$,
in words, the distance from $1$ to the subspace generated by $x,x^2, \ldots,x^n$ equals $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Now we have
$$d^2 = \frac{G(1,x,\ldots, x^n)}{G(x,x^2, \ldots, x^n)}$$
where the $G$'s are [Gram determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant) that can be calculated with the formula for [Cauchy determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix#Cauchy_determinants).

$\bf{Added:}$ One sees easily that the Gram matrix for the system of functions $(x^{\alpha_i})$ is the symmetric Cauchy matrix $(\frac{1}{\alpha_i + \alpha_j+1})$, with determinant $V(\alpha_i)\cdot\prod_{i,j} \frac{1}{\alpha_i + \alpha_j+1}$, where $V$ is the Vandermonde determinant. We get for the distance squared $d^2$ from $x^{\alpha}$ to the span of $(x^{\alpha_i})_i$

$$d^2=\frac{G(x^{\alpha},x^{\alpha_i})}{G(x^{\alpha_i})}=\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}\prod_i \frac{(\alpha_i-\alpha)^2}{(\alpha_i+\alpha+1)^2}$$
For $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha_i=i$, with $1\le i \le n$, we get the desired value
$\frac{(n!)^2}{(n+1)!^2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$.

Comment: Beating calculus via Linear Algebra. +1